# Odoo 12 : How to enable Chat with workers enabled

Tags: nginx, odoo-12

I'm working on deploying Odoo on my local machine using nginx (**for local use only**).
The problem is that the chat stil not working even if I seted correct parameters both in odoo.conf and in ngnix.
Let me show you my configurations.
`Here is my`[odoo.conf](https://pastebin.com/Bz4WfxdF).
`Here is my`[nginx](https://pastebin.com/zswtkrTE) conf (etc/nginx/sites-available/odoo) that is already linked to sites-enabled.
The thing is, when I go localhost:80, I get nginx page.
And still get `these` [erros](https://pastebin.com/G9jZE6Q3) message in Odoo.

Answer (score 0):

I correct my nginx conf to :

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
server 127.0.0.1:8088;
}
upstream odoochat {
server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

# http -> https
server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
# Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

# log
access_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/odoo.error.log;

# Redirect requests to odoo backend server
location / {
 proxy_redirect off;
 proxy_pass http://odoo;
}
location /longpolling {
  proxy_pass http://odoochat;
}
}
```